# Can not find the declaration of element 'persistence' , element persistence missing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Have put the `persistence.xml` in the classpath of the project in eclipse because before the error was that the file was not found. Now gives this error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml. Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-elt.1: Can not find the declaration of element 'persistence'
```

[image]

here is my file:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.1"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DataSource" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>JTA persistence unit related to the datasource DataSource</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate_DataSource.cfg.xml"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="securityStore" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>JTA persistence unit related to the datasource securityStore</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate_securityStore.cfg.xml"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not find the declaration of element 'persistence'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818737/can-not-find-the-declaration-of-element-persistence)

Comment: Hello, no it does not..

Answer (score 0):

According to the JPA spec (see section 8.2.1 **persistence.xml file**):

> A `persistence.xml` file defines a persistence unit. The `persistence.xml` file is located in the `META-INF` directory of the root of the persistence unit.

So, try to put your `persistence.xml` in the `META-INF` directory.

P.S. Maybe you application actually use not the `persistence.xml` what you expect, but placed somewhere in the classpath in `META-INF` directory.

Comment: in fact , 

I'm working with Ireport 3.0.0 , i'm having dificulties in parsing my persistence.xml file wich  works with jpa 2.1 version (hibernate 5.1.14-final)..so my question is does ireport 3.0.0 supports jpa 2.1.if not , any further solution?

Comment: Hello community,

I'm working with Ireport 3.0.0 , i'm having dificulties in parsing my persistence.xml file wich  works with jpa 2.1 version (hibernate 5.1.14-final)..so my question is does ireport 3.0.0 supports jpa 2.1.if not , any further solution?